# Not able to set Email updates and not receiving email notifications for stackexchange salesforce

Tags: discussion, bug

From few days i am not getting email notifications when new question is posted on [salesforce.stackexchange.com](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com) .Also i am not able to edit the email settings for the notifications .This is very weird .Is any one else facing this issue ?

[image]

Comment: I am getting email without any issue.